# disminuir el valor de un cadena

Tags: python

Tengo esta lista:

```
lista1 = [['5C', '7E', '10R'],['5T', '5R', '6R'],['7R', '9E', '2T']]
```

necesito disminuir los valores, es decir la lista que tengo que obtener es:

```
lista2 = [['4C', '6E', '9R'],['4T', '4R', '5R'],['6R', '8E', '1T']]
```

existe alguna forma rápida de hacer esto??

Comment: Podrias recorrer la lista,  hacer un split y al primer carácter de cada objeto restarle 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dijiste algo rápido, pues con comprensión y [slicing](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+slicing)

```
>>> y = ['5C', '7E', '10R']
>>> [str(int(x[:-1])-1)+x[-1] for x in y]
['4C', '6E', '9R']
>>>
>>> # Lo anterior era solo prueba, ahora implementándolo:
>>> 
>>> lista1 = [['5C', '7E', '10R'], ['5T', '5R', '6R'], ['7R', '9E', '2T']]
>>> [[str(int(x[:-1])-1)+x[-1] for x in y] for y in lista1]
[['4C', '6E', '9R'], ['4T', '4R', '5R'], ['6R', '8E', '1T']]
```